# Copying values into a spreadsheet if the value does not exist already - Google Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to:

1. Go into a Drive folder and retrieve the spreadSheetIDs of existing spreadsheets
2. Go into each spreadsheet and get some data
3. Copy that data into a TargetSheet
4. With the condition that the data does not exist already

From 1-3 I have no issues, but I cannot correctly search and match if the data exists already.

This is my code so far. If I run the code twice on the same data set, some data is copied when it should not be, since it already exists.

Any help, please?

```
function getReportData() {

//Sources
var reportFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('ReportFolderID') // Get Status reports folder
var reportsList = reportFolder.getFiles(); //Returns FileIterator object
var spreadSheets = [];
var targetSSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('TargetSheetID');
var targetSheet = targetSSheet.getActiveSheet();
var lastRow = targetSheet.getLastRow();

var searchRange = targetSheet.getRange(2, 1, lastRow, 2);
var searchRangeV = searchRange.getValues();
var allStatuses = [];


//Populate the reportSheets list with latest report sheet IDs
while (reportsList.hasNext()) {
    var reports = reportsList.next(); //Object of type file
    spreadSheets.push(reports.getId());
}


// Loop through the list of report sheets
for (i = 0; i < spreadSheets.length; i++) {
    var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadSheets[i]);
    var activeSheet = spreadSheet.getActiveSheet();
    var individualStatus = [];


    // Gets project report data
    var projectName = activeSheet.getRange("B3:B4").getValue();
    var reportDate = activeSheet.getRange("I3:I4").getValue();
    var projectStatus = activeSheet.getRange("G9:i9").getValue();

    // Creates reports array
    individualStatus.push(reportDate, projectName, projectStatus);

    allStatuses.push(individualStatus)

}

   //Cleans the status array of existing ones
for (j = 0; j < allStatuses.length; j++) {

    var searchKey = allStatuses[j][0] + allStatuses[j][1];
    searchKey

    Logger.log(searchKey)

    for (k = 0; k < searchRangeV.length; k++) {

        var matchKey = searchRangeV[k][0] + searchRangeV[k][1];

        if (searchKey == matchKey) {
            allStatuses.splice(j, 1)
            break;
        } else {
            Logger.log(searchKey)
            Logger.log(matchKey)
        }

    }
}

//Copies the data to Target Sheet
for (var project = 0; project < allStatuses.length; project++) {
    //Gets the last row each time it goes through the loop
    var latestRow = targetSheet.getLastRow();
    var lastColumn = targetSheet.getLastColumn();

    for (var status = 0; status < allStatuses[project].length; status++) {

        targetSheet.getRange(latestRow + 1, status + 1, 1, 1).setValue(allStatuses[project][status])


    }
}
```

}

Comment: You might like to change this line `var reportsList = reportFolder.getFiles(); //Returns FileIterator object` to something like this `var reportsList = reportFolder.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS); //Returns FileIterator object`

Comment: Also these lines return multiple values in a 2D array: `var projectName = activeSheet.getRange("B3:B4").getValue();
    var reportDate = activeSheet.getRange("I3:I4").getValue();
    var projectStatus = activeSheet.getRange("G9:i9").getValue();` so you should change getValue() to getValues() and figure out what your declarations really are.

Comment: The ranges are cells in a template that is in the active sheet of the spreadsheets.


What do you think I'm doing wrong at the search and copy?

Comment: if you use `activeSheet.getRange("G9:i9").getValue();` it makes no sense because there is more than one cell.  If you get anything then you just be getting `G9` the upper left corner cell.